# Necesito que alguien me explique como funciona este codigo que es para mostrar nodos insertados en un arbol binario en c++

Tags: c++

Necesito que alguien me explique como funciona este código que es para mostrar nodos insertados en un árbol binario en c++
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es muy fácil, es un código que es para mostrar nodos insertados en un árbol binario en [tag:c++], funciona ejecutando una línea cada vez hasta que no quedan más líneas en el programa.

Comment: si bro pero es que estoy en un curso , y no puedo avanzar sin saber como funciona el codigo , como son los llamados a la funcion y todo eso . Ten la bondad de explicarme por favor

Comment: @KennySilva si no sabes cómo funciona el código, el profesor ha hecho mal su trabajo.

Comment: pues si se lo que esta haciendo el codigo ,pero me confundo en la parte de recursividad.

Comment: Te haré unas recomendaciones: lee [ask], cuando preguntes no coloques el código como imagen no es necesario ni bien visto, cuando tengas dudas procura exponer lo que si comprendes y se tan específico en lo que no entiendes así como lo investigado de modo que recibas respuestas enfocadas y no solo largos texto genéricos como ahorita, así los demás sabrán como ayudarte; lo anterior por que al momento tu pregunta es muy amplia ya que da a entender que no entiendes nada del tema de recursividad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trataré de explicar lo mejor que pueda.

El código que tienes ahí, como bien dices, es para mostrar los nodos en un árbol. Ahora bien, lo característico del código y que debes manejar muy bien para entenderlo es el tema de "Recursividad". En pocas palabras lo que tienes ahí es un método que primero verifica si el nodo (variable del nombre arbol) existe, Si no existe, pues termina el método... y aquí viene la magia: Si existe el nodo, se llama así mismo (el método) y lo seguirá haciendo hasta que no encuentre más nodos en la dirección "der". Cuando no encuentre más nodos, te mostrará en la dirección "izq" hasta que no encuentre tampoco más nodos allí... cuando se libere todo el stack de llamadas del método (las veces que se ha llamado a si mismo), terminará mostrandote en consola (COUT) todos los nodos del árbol.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Aunque esté escrito en otro lenguaje, acá te explican muy bien como se lee un árbol binario en estructura recursiva:
https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythoned/Trees/RecorridosDeArboles.html

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Los enlaces a los que se refiere @ivanao son estos: [answer] y [tour]

Comment: Gracias, compañeros. Me leeré el recorrido.